# Add Authorization Header After AJAX Call

Tags: angularjs, restful-authentication, jwt

I'm working on a web application with Angular.JS and Node.JS as the back-end.
On my login page, I'm using an AJAX call to perform the login. Upon a success login, I would like to redirect the browser to a new page but I need to add the am authorization header based on the login response.

For future AJAX calls I use Angular interceptor to add the token to each request but my problem is how to add it to the redirect call.

```
$http
    .post('/api/authentication/login', dataToPost)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
                window.location.replace("/");
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: You are storing the token in session storage, so after redirect you must check if the token exist, set the header based on that within angular `.run` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the headers like this way.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = $window.sessionStorage.token
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm not doing an AJAX call. I need to redirect to a new page.